# Security-Constraint without role mapping

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, web.xml

what is the best way to configure a part of my web application so that you must authenticate but do not need to be in a special group?

I ask because in my JAX-RS service every user should be allowed to access any resource by default and I do not want to map every user to a default group.

Thanks in advance, CQQL

Edit:
The answer is to just use * as the role-name in the auth-constraint.

Comment: I have the same problem:  require authentication, but accept any roles for authenticated users.  When I use '*' as the role-name, then GlassFish (3.1.2) doesn't require authentication.